# Use sample() without replacement multiple times with increasing sample size in R

Tags: r, sample

I want to take "random" samples from a vector called `data` but with increasing `size` and without replacement.

To illustrate my point `data` looks for example like:

```
data<-c("a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","x","c","v","b","n","m")
```

What I need is to get different sampling vectors with increasing sampling size (starting with size=2) for example by 2 but without duplicates between the different vectors and store everything into a list so that the result would look something like this:

```
sample_1<-c("s","d")
sample_2<-c("s","d","a","f")
sample_3<-c("s","d","a","f","m","n")
sample_4<-c("s","d","a","f","m","n","l","c")
sample_5<-c("s","d","a","f","m","n","l","c","j","x")
sample_6<-c("s","d","a","f","m","n","l","c","j","x","v","k")
sample_7<-c("s","d","a","f","m","n","l","c","j","x","v","k","g","b")
sample_8<-c("s","d","a","f","m","n","l","c","j","x","v","k","g","b","h")
samples<-list(sample_1,sample_2,sample_3,sample_4,sample_5,sample_6,sample_7,sample_8)
```

What i have so far is:

```
samples<-sapply(seq(from=2, to=length(data), by=2), function(i) sample(data,size=i,replace=F),simplify=F,USE.NAMES=T )
```

What does not work is to have the increasing sample size but keeping the samples of the previous steps and to have a last list element with all observations.
Is something like this possible?

Comment: In brief you want `sample(data,size=length(data))` and every subsets of it ?

Comment: I edited my answer after seing your comment, check if it better match your need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understood you correctly, but perhaps you only need to scramble the data once:

```
data = letters
data_random = sample(data)
sapply(seq(from=2, to=length(data), by=2),
       function (x) data_random[1:x],
       simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thats pretty much what i need. But would it be possible to not take the "additional" samples according to the order in `data_random`?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "not take the additional samples according to the order in `data_random`"

Comment: If Im not mistaken your code creates the `data_random` object and then goes trough the values within it and adds two additional (remaining) values to every next list (bigger sample size). It does not choose the values which are added in every step "randomly" from `data_random`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I see what you mean now. Do you want to allow that the chosen elements from `data_random` after a certain iteration (e.g. `s` and `d` from your example after step 1) to be sampled again, i.e. with replacement as it were? If that is *not* the case I'd argue that shuffling the data once is enough. This randomises the order of the elements in `data` completely. If you would shuffle the remaining items again, you'd actually shuffle a shuffled vector, I don't see any benefit in that.

Comment: Well now that you say so...I thought of making it as random as possible...but making it random once should actually be enough or better said i can not think of an argument against your point :P

Answer (score 4):

After your comments on other answer I think I get what you want to achieve, so extending my previous code I end up with:

```
data<-c("a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","x","c","v","b","n","m")
set.seed(123)
nbitems=length(data)/2+length(data)%%2
results=vector("list",nbitems)

results[[1]] <- sample(data,2) # get first sample
for (i in 2:nbitems) { # Loop for each result
  samplesavail <- data[!data %in% results[[i-1]]] # Reduce the samples available
  results[[i]] <- c(results[[i-1]], sample( samplesavail, min( length(samplesavail), 2) ) ) # concatenate a new sample, size depends on step and remaining samples available.
}
```

Hope this match your intended use:

```
> results
[[1]]
[1] "n" "f"

[[2]]
[1] "n" "f" "a" "g"

[[3]]
[1] "n" "f" "a" "g" "m" "v"

[[4]]
[1] "n" "f" "a" "g" "m" "v" "x" "l"

[[5]]
 [1] "n" "f" "a" "g" "m" "v" "x" "l" "b" "j"

[[6]]
 [1] "n" "f" "a" "g" "m" "v" "x" "l" "b" "j" "k" "h"

[[7]]
 [1] "n" "f" "a" "g" "m" "v" "x" "l" "b" "j" "k" "h" "d" "s"

[[8]]
 [1] "n" "f" "a" "g" "m" "v" "x" "l" "b" "j" "k" "h" "d" "s" "c"
```

---

Previous approach:

If I understood you well (but far unsure):

```
data<-c("a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","x","c","v","b","n","m")
set.seed(123) # fix the seed for repro of answer, remove in real case
nbitems=length(data)/2+length(data)%%2 # Get how much entries we should have when stepping by 2
results=vector("list",nbitems) # preallocate the list (as we'll start by end)
results[[nbitems]] = sample(data,length(data)) # sample the datas
for (i in nbitems:2) {
  results[[i-1]] <- results[[i]][1:(length(results[[i]]) - 2)] # for each iteration, take down the 2 last entries.
}
```

This give a single entry as first result.

Just noticed this is the same idea as @sbstn answer but with a more complicated backward approach, posting in case it can have some value.